# What is this "Can you help?" message above the answer box?

Tags: discussion, answers

I was looking at a new question on main ([Where and what was Haunt.bat? A game pre-loaded on a c1992 PC](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1985/621)) and saw this message above the answer box:

[image: Message]

What is this message?  Was it added by a mod?  I don't see it on any other question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was, in fact, A/B testing:  To quote [Adam Lear on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289234/242209):

> We're currently running an experiment with different versions of a
>   call to action on questions.
>
> The original version is
>
> > Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, Google+, Twitter, or Facebook.
>
> The new copy being tested is
>
> > Can you help? SiteName depends on everyone sharing their knowledge. If you're able to answer this question, please do!
>
> The original is still shown to users on their own questions (since
>   it's weird to prompt them to also *answer*) and people who aren't part
>   of the experiment group.

Answer (score 3):

Look again at the question.  That message has gone away and the usual box has returned.  I can confirm that the message you describe was there just after the question was posted,

A very similar message box is visible on some questions on other sites too.  Although I've only seen it on beta sites so far.

No, it isn't a moderator message.  StackExchange does alter things from time to time, I believe this is just a new message of encouragement.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is an alternative message to the "Know someone who can answer?" message. <s>I see a different banner both when logged in and not, so I assume this is not specific to this question.</s>
***EDIT 2016/01/11:*** Now I see this banner too.

[image: Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, Google+, Twitter, or Facebook.]

Post notices added by moderators appear above the question's comments, and there is no option that I can find that allows custom notices such as this to be shown; there is only **citation needed**, **current event** and **insufficient explanation**.